# How to implement single sign-on between .NET Core & ASP.NET webforms application

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms, single-sign-on

I have two projects, one in ASP.NET webforms and another in ASP.NET Core across multiple domains. How can I implement single sign on?

Comment: do you have a identity provider, like Azure AD, Okta, Google Worksapce?